# Messages sent with Gmail API get marked as suspicious when sending to Gmail addresses

Tags: gmail-api

Messages sent through the Gmail API to a Gmail address are getting tagged in Gmail with

```
Be careful with this message. It contains content that's typically used to steal personal information.
```

The message basically just says test. And the identical content message sent through Gmail SMTP doesn't get tagged with that warning.

It seems really strange that Gmail would mark messages that are coming through a Gmail owned API as suspicious but when they come through SMTP it does not warn about it.

Comment: This has started happening recently in our Gmail API integration as well, any help/solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

I was getting this as well. Simply removing the 'from' portion of the email solved it for me. If you are authenticated gmail figures that stuff out on its own.

Comment: This answer should be accepted. Worked for me as well.

Comment: Thanks so much @Matthew! Worked for me as well!

Comment: What if I'd like to send the email with a name for the "from" address?